# I can link to the CDN on the jQuery-ui site (the "official jQuery CDN") but I can't link to Google's . Why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cdn

My jQuery-UI code executes perfectly when I link to Media Temple's ProCDN - the one provided on the jQuery - UI site :

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

When I try linking to the Google hosted version however, it takes much longer to load and the jQuery code is not implemented on the web page :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I really don't know why I'm not able to go the Google route.

Comment: Is the difference in jQuery UI version intended? With Google you're linking to jQuery UI 1.9.1 instead of 1.10.2

Comment: No it's not. Even linking to 1.10.2 on Google doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Your Google links don't have "http://" - so if you're using it locally it will try to load "file://ajax.googleapis.com"

Just add http:// to the beginning.

Comment: This is not true.

// refers to http:// or https:// depending on your local server. It won't link to any file:// stuff

Unless: you're opening a HTML file directly in your browser.

Comment: @ErikNijland no, jqueryrocks is correct.  // tells the browser to use the same protocol as the page it is rendering.  If you are accessing a locally stored HTML file, it will point at file://, if you are looking at a page over http, it will be http://, if your are looking at a page over https, it will be https://.